# Collision is not working

Tags: swift, collision

I am trying to make a platorm game. I have made a level in GameScene.sks but I couldn't figure out how to detect collisions in between the sis file and the player, so I decided to use a level node instead. I have the code for turning the nodes into 32 bit numbers, and I have it put into eh code before the self.addchild, but it does not seem to work. Any help?

```
struct collisionPhysics {
    static let alien: UInt32 = 1 << 0
    static let level: UInt32 = 1 << 1
```

}

```
        alien.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = collisionPhysics.alien
    alien.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = collisionPhysics.level
    alien.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = collisionPhysics.level
    level.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = collisionPhysics.level
    level.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = collisionPhysics.alien
    level.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = collisionPhysics.alien
```

James

Comment: 1) Check if you have set `physicsWorld.contactDelegate` property. 2) See if you properly handle contacts in `didBeginContact` method. 3) Check if at least one body is defined as dynamic. Contact will not happen if both bodies are defined as static ( `physicsBody.dynamic = false` ).

Comment: Also note that edge based physics bodies, unlike volume based bodies, are static by default (they act like `dynamic` property is set to false).

Comment: @Whirlwind Only the alien is dynamic. Is the contact delegate where you define the borders and contact like "circleofradius"? Because I was tying to figure that out and used `sprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithTexture:sprite.texture size:sprite.texture.size];` from the apple developer page, but it would not work. I have no idea how to call a didBeginContact Method.

Comment: Your scene has to conform to `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` protocol. Then you have to set `self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self` for example in your `didMoveToView` method. This delegates responsibility of handling contacts to the scene.